# Python coding - list index out of range

Tags: python, python-2.7, xlrd

lots of code up here

...

```
if c==excelfiles[1]:
    b ==excelfiles[1]
    wb = xlrd.open_workbook(a)
    wb.sheet_names()
    sh = wb.sheet_by_index(0)
    for rownum in range(sh.nrows):
        print sh.row_values(rownum)

for i in range(sheet.nrows):
    cashflow = [sheet.cell_value(i,0)],[sheet.cell_value(i,1)],[sheet.cell_value(i,2)]
    print cashflow

def npv(rate, cashflow):
    value = cashflow[1] * ((1 + rate/100) ** (12 - cashflow[0]))
    FV = 0
    FV += value
    return FV

def irr(cashflow, iterations = 100):
    rate = 1.0

    i = 0
    while (cashflow[0][1] == 0):
        i += 1

    investment = cashflow[i][1]

    for i in range(1, iterations+1):
        rate *= (1 - (npv(rate, cashflow) / investment))
        return rate

r = irr(cashflow)

print r
```

Error/Output:

```
  File "<pyshell#90>", line 1, in <module>
    import quarterZ
  File "quarterZ.py", line 65, in <module>
    r = irr(cashflow) # why is list index out of range?
  File "quarterZ.py", line 56, in irr
    while (cashflow[0][1] == 0):
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Can someone please explain why my list index is out of range? And can you show me how to fix this? I am relatively new to python so I'm sure it's a stupid mistake.

Thanks so much!

I've also attached the code here: http://ideone.com/G5hGuK

Answer (score 0):

`cashflow[0]` is set to `[sheet.cell_value(i,0)]` in your for loop on line 10, which is a list with length 1. The expression `cashflow[0][1]` is trying to read the second value in that list.